# WordPress Products - Attribute multi field and ACF frontend

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, attributes

[Here is what I’m trying to achieve.](http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/26308/nike-air-zoom-talaria-mid-fk-premium)

Based on the region (EU, UK, US), you can choose the size.

I think that I am missing some knowledge where to put these parts of code as I am trying to put everything inside 'function.php' but it's only displaying me the switcher.

I’ve added 2 more custom fields in the Attribute size (UK, US).

[Website I'm working on](https://eshoes.com.au/product/martini-osvaldo-728-suede-blue/)

Attribute slug: size

Variables added with ACF: uk-size, us-size

My attribute default value: EU

Code I would like to put in my wordpress (but don't know the location to add them):

**Php snippet**

```
$us_size = get_field('us_size', $term);
    $uk_size = get_field('uk_size', $term);
    $cm_size = get_field('cm_size', $term);
    printf( '<div class="sizeRadio">
        <input type="radio" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" id="%3$s" %4$s>
        <label for="%3$s">
        <span class="label_show" data-region="eu">%5$s</span>
        <span data-region="us">%6$s</span>
        <span data-region="uk">%7$s</span>
        <span data-region="cm">%8$s</span>
        </label>
        </div>', $input_name, $esc_value, $id, $checked, $filtered_label, $us_size, $uk_size, $cm_size );
}
```

**JS snippet**

```
$('[data-chooseregion]').on('click', function(e) {
                        $(this).addClass('active--sizeSelect').siblings().removeClass('active--sizeSelect');

                        var $active = $('[data-region=' + $(this).data('chooseregion') + ']').addClass('label_show');

                        $('[data-region]').not($active).removeClass('label_show');
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

**Markup for the switcher**

```
<?php
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect active--sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="eu" href="#">EU</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="us" href="#" >US</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="uk" href="#" >UK</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="cm" href="#" >CM</a>';
?>
```

Anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sort it out and instead of creating a "dynamic" data's change, I chose to create a table from the 2 fields under my pa_size as follow:

```
if(!empty($terms)){
    echo '<button class="accordion">Size Chart <i class="fa-sitemap"></i></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <table class="sf-table standard_bordered"><tbody><tr><td><strong>EU</strong></td>';
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $eu_s .'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr><tr><td><strong>UK</strong></td>';
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $uk_s = get_field('uk-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $uk_s .'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr><tr><td><strong>US</strong></td>';   
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $us_s = get_field('us-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $us_s .'</td>';
                }   
            echo '</tr></tbody></table></div>';
}
```

Don't hesitate if any question about it.

Cheers